# Syncing writes and not deletes - mongoDB

Tags: replication, mongodb

Is it possible to have a secondary instance of mongoDB which syncs all the write operations to the database and not the delete operation?

I'm looking for this solution so that I have a backup even if some humane error occurs and data is lost.

Comment: Well, of course it is possible and MongoDB Inc sells a backup solution for some big money (and people are paying it) just because the fun of it. ;) It is kind of easy to implement, however – create a snapshot of the data and read the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). The details, however, are a wee bit more complicated.